# How to create 'object' containing a polygon and variables and other data elements

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, polygon

Okay this is my first WPF app and I am having a hard run of knowing what it is I'm looking for. So here is what I'm trying to do, been googling for 4 hours now and not found a solution that fits the bill.

I'm trying to write a simple game ui, it is grid/tile based, and i have the grid built using grid column and row definitions and I'm successfully placing objects in various grid locations.
I am currently stuck as trying to build the player object. I want a single object reference to represent the various components of the players piece.

Currently I am using a polygon to represent the piece on the grid. Eventually I want to replace this with images or something.
I want to add in properties for what weapon and armor it has equipped
I want properties for health

Essentially in code i want something like this

```
dim player1 as new playerobject

player1.polygon.points = 0,0 60,30 0,60

player1.health = 100

player1.weapon = "axe"
```

etc

I can instantiate all this as separate variables etc, but I'd like to have a singular reference that contains all the variables, properties, objects, controls etc.

I'm using vb .net in vs 2010 (and no, I'm not looking to write in something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

playerobject needs to be a class with

```
 public List<Int> Points { get; set; }

 public string Weapon { get; set; }

 public Int Health { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks - feels like a brain fart- - I've been running on fumes, was up till 3:30 playing with it, and woke up at 7 for work. Was thinking you could build it in the xaml which explains why Google was not returning results.

Comment: Troelson C# and the .NET Platform is a great book.  XAML is really just there to build and arrange the visual objects.  You get some sorting and triggers in XAML but it is not a really programming environment.